# Comparing last-modified date

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file

I am trying to translate a linux bash script to windows. I have two questions:

- How to strip the extension part of a filename?
- How to compare the last-modified date of two files?

The original bash script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
name=${file%.*}

if [ "$1.scala" -ot "$file" ]; then
    java -jar ./potigol/potigol.jar -d $file > $name.scala
fi
./scala-2.11.8/bin/scala -save -cp potigol/potigol.jar $name.scala 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Open up a command prompt and read the help for the `CALL` and `FOR` commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @squashman. I found the answer in the help of the `CALL` and `FOR` commands:

```
@echo off
SET scala_file=%~n1.scala
SET t1=%~t1
FOR %%A IN (%scala_file%) DO (SET t2=%%~tA)
IF "%t1%" GTR "%t2%" (
    java -jar potigol\potigol.jar -d %1 > %scala_file%
)
scala-2.11.8\bin\scala -save -cp potigol\potigol.jar %scala_file% 2> NUL
```